# Powershell using a different delimiter to add-content to output values in CSV

Tags: powershell

I am facing an issue whereby one of my column A contents includes a comma in it, resulting in inserting the remaining contents into column B. I tried to use delimiter but it wasn't supported for `Add-Content`

Example of the value `$contentA = "This product has the ability to x,y,z"`

The x,y,z will be under columns A, B, C respectively which is not desired.

The desired outcome should be everything under column A.

```
   $result = @(
       "$contentA,$contentB,$contentC,$contentD"        
    )
    
    $Result| foreach {
        Add-Content -Path $global:csvFile -Value $_
    }
```

Comment: You would use export-CSV, not add-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're **better off declaring your new rows as *objects*** - with properties matching all columns in the target CSV - and letting PowerShell take care of quoting for you, via **[`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv)**:

```sh
[array] $result = 
  [pscustomobject] @{
    A = $contentA
    B = $contentB
    C = $contentC
    D = $contentD
  }, # ... additional objects, if needed.

$result | Export-Csv -Append t.csv
```

--

While you *could* perform ***plain-text* handling** with [`Add-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content) by **enclosing each variable reference in embedded `"..."`**, this potentially requires you to also handle escaping of value-embedded `"` characters (as `""`) - again, `Export-Csv` handles that for you.

If column values containing `"` aren't a concern, but *performance* is, you could fix your approach as follows (PSv4+):

```sh
$result = @(
  ($contentA, $contentB, $contentC, $contentD).ForEach({ "`"$_`"" }) -join ','
)

Add-Content -Path $global:csvFile -Value $result
```